# How to create a custom lightning web component for Knowledge Articles to show article title and article body only?

Tags: articles, lightning-knowledge, lightning-web-components

I have been trying to create a lwc that will only show the article title and body within our community. so far I am running into some trouble with the lightning record view form commnd and assigning a proper record id as our community has dynamic pages. i . am hoping that someone can help me figure out how to either hide the other fields or to just display the article body and title fields. I am using visual studio to create the lwc.

html:

```
<template>
   <lightning-record-view-form record-id="ka0170000009rYcAAI" object-api-name="Knowledge__kav">
      <div class="slds-grid">
            <div class="slds-col slds-size_1-of-2">
                 <lightning-output-field field-name= "Title">
            </div>
            <div class="slds-col slds-size_1-of-2">
                 <lightning-output-field field-name="Article_body__c"
            </div>
   </lightning-record-view-form>
</template>
```

js:

```
// myComponent.js
import { LightningElement, api } from 'lwc';
export default class MyComponent extends LightningElement {
    @api recordId;
}
```

js-meta.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<LightningComponentBundle xmlns="http://soap.sforce.com/2006/04/metadata">
<apiVersion>47.0</apiVersion>
<isExposed><targets>
<target>lightningCommunity__Page</target>
<target>lightningCommunity__Default</target>
</targets></isExposed>
</LightningComponentBundle>
```

Answer (score 1):

The lightning data service does not support the Knowledge__kav object as per the [User Interface API guide](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.uiapi.meta/uiapi/ui_api_get_started_supported_objects.htm). It is supported in Lightning communities container but your object is not supported. Hence, You need to explicitly make an apex call to get the record.

A sample example would be:-

```
        <template if:true={article}>
            <p>{article.Title}</p>
            <p>{article.Article_body__c}</p>
        </template>
```

Javascript file:-

```
import { LightningElement, api, track} from 'lwc';
import findArticles from '@salesforce/apex/KnowledgeController.findArticles';

export default class ApexImperativeMethodWithParams extends LightningElement {
     @api recordId;
     @track article;
     @track error;

     connectedCallback() {
        findArticles({ knowledgerecordid: this.recordId})
            .then(result => {
                this.article= result;
                this.error = undefined;
            })
            .catch(error => {
                this.error = error;
                this.article= undefined;
            });
    }
}
```

Check out this:- [trailheadapps/lwc-recipes](https://github.com/trailheadapps/lwc-recipes/tree/master/force-app/main/default/lwc)

Comment: As of 2020-04-14, I can see that KnowledgeArticleVersion is now in that list of supported objects you linked to, but I had no success using lighting-record-view-form or the getRecord method from the uiRecordApi, or any other method suggested for lwc ( https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/component-library/documentation/en/lwc/lwc.data_load_record) to get a field from a KnowledgeArticleVersion :(

Ended up following your route, using a custom Apex controller (this was with Classic Knowledge, that might have something to do with it)

Answer (score 0):

Try to receive `recordId` from community component setting like

```
<targetConfigs>
  <targetConfig targets="lightningCommunity__Default">
      <property name="recordId" type="String" />
  </targetConfig>
</targetConfigs>
```

And set `{!recordId}` on it like the standard article detail component.
[image]

Comment: Set a default so admins don't need to worry about explicitly setting the {!recordId} string in app builder. E.g. <property name="recordId" type="String" default="{!recordId}" />